# How to crop and scale correctly with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, scale, crop

I'm trying to remove the TOP AND BOTTOM black bars of a video.

Image sample from video
[image]

What i'm trying to achieve

[image]

The video itself is 1280x720 16:9, but the portion that's image information *is* at 4:3 since it's been captured from a VHS. I want to somehow stretch it until the top bars disappear without deforming the image. I don't care about the left and right bars.

I tried using `crop` and `scale` with no luck.

By using this code the top and bottom black bars disappeared on VLC when on *normal screen* but when going Full Screen the bars appeared again.

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi -filter:v "crop=1280:670" output_video.mp4
```

I thought it had something to do with the Scale of the video but honestly every `scale` code I tried to use deformed the image a lot.

I hope someone can help me, fairly new to FFMPEG but really enjoying it this far.

Comment: The player will add the letterboxing to fit your screen in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 25):

I got your image, resized it to 720p, made a 30 second video to test.

In my example I've also cropped the edges (left/right) because as @LordNeckbeard mentioned, when they hit the side of your screen, they may prevent the top/bottom of the video from reaching the top/bottom of the screen, which will again, look like black bars at the top/bottom, whether they are there or not.

This worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i "test.avi" -filter:v "crop=iw-400:ih-40,scale=960:720" -pix_fmt yuv420p output_video.mp4
```

**Quick explanation:**

`crop=iw-400:ih-40`
Cropping 400 from the input width (iw) (2x200 left/right)
Cropping 40 from the input height (ih) (2x20 top/bottom)
You can cut a little more off if you want a 'crisper' edge.

`scale=960:720`
Scaling the video slightly to bring it back to your original 720p, the 960 is to keep it at a nice 4x3 ratio.
This scaling is not needed, your preference.

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Hey that worked! Thanks a lot for your time and your help!

Comment: Wait, how to crop without centering?

Comment: One important point to be noted is that the `-filter:v` (or `-vf`) option can only be used once. The last one is the one that acts on the data (previous instances are silently ignored).